# Angular 2 Nested Modal Dialog with PrimeNG doesn't work

Tags: html, angular, primeng, primeng-dialog

I am using the PrimeNG dialog component and I have a modal dialog from which, on the click of a button, I want to show another modal dialog.

What is happening is that my second modal dialog is not really modal, because I only see the content of the dialog following the button.

I do change [appendTo] attribute of the p-dialog for the second modal dialog but it does not seem to work properly.

How can I open nested dialog in a p-dialog?

Dialog in a angular 2 component:

```
<p-dialog header="Create/Edit Financial Flow"  [visible]="display$ | async" modal="modal" width="500" height="600" responsive="true" [resizable]="false" [closable]="false">
<financial-flowdialog #myfinancialflowdialog (onCloseDialog) ="closeDialog()" [flowdata]="selectedFlows$ | async"></financial-flowdialog>
</p-dialog>
```

When clicking a button within the first modal dialog, should open a second dialog. Below the definition of the nested dialog:

```
    <p-dialog header="Title" [(visible)]="display" [appendTo]="body" *ngIf="display" modal="modal" width="500" height="600" responsive="true"
        [resizable]="false" [closable]="false">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <form (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">

                <div class="pull-right top-buffer ">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" (click)="closeDialog()">Cancel</button>
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Select</button>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </p-dialog>
    <button type="button" #mybtn [value]="value" ngDefaultControl [formControlName]="key" [id]="key" [ngStyle]="style" (click)="openDialog()">{{label}}</button>
```

I can open the first dialog but when I click on the button to open the second dialog, the content of dialog shows up like a normal div. Below the html rendered:

```
<section>
    <div id="nestediag" ng-reflect-form="[object Object]" class="ng-pristine ng-invalid ng-touched">
        <!--template bindings={
  "ng-reflect-ng-if": "true"
}--><p-dialog header="Title" height="600" modal="modal" responsive="true" width="500" ng-reflect-visible="true">
            <div class="container-fluid">
                <form class="ng-untouched ng-pristine ng-valid">

                    <div class="pull-right top-buffer ">
                        <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button">Cancel</button>
                        <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Select</button>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        </p-dialog>
        <button ngdefaultcontrol="" type="button" value="Select a payee" ng-reflect-name="flowpayee" ng-reflect-ng-style="[object Object]" ng-reflect-value="Select a payee" ng-reflect-id="flowpayee" id="flowpayee" class="ng-pristine ng-valid ng-touched" style="width: 100%;">Select a payee</button>
    </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Defining a componentref variable and using [appendTo]="Componentref" solve the issue.
See discussion https://github.com/primefaces/primeng/issues/656

Comment: I wish you could explain this with an example

Answer (score 22):

You can solve this problem by appending the second dialog to the document body by using the appendTo attribute, e.g.

```
<p-dialog appendTo="body">
...
</p-dialog>
```

Comment: appendTo="body" is not working. The submit button is doing nothing.

Comment: I have a Dynamic Dialog that is calling an Dialog (the nested dialog, p-dialog). I added appendTo = "body" in the nested dialog, but it is not working I am able to return and interchange information in the first Dialog (modal is not working). Maybe is by the combination of Dynamic Dialog and Dialog. I do not know it.

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this problem by appending the second dialog to the document body by using the appendTo attribute,  for e.g.

```
<p-dialog appendTo="body">
.............
</p-dialog>
```